# The tel URI for Telephone Numbers in mobile mail services (Gmail,Yahoo Mail, Thunderbird etc.)

Tags: html, email-attachments, email, tel

I have created a web page with a  tel scheme link, this links works fine when the web page is opened in the mobile browser.

I want to send this webpage as a mail body like a e-mailer, using [emailtheweb.com](http://emailtheweb.com) where it captures the webpage and sends it as the webpage in e-mail body.

When i open the mail  in my gmail app on android or ios and click the link created with the tel scheme functionality it wont work. Rather it redirects me to the link in a web browser of mobile example: www.xyz.com/tel:+000000000

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?  Where after clicking the link in the gmail app it can call the number?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: `<a target="_blank" href="tel:00493012345678">link</a>` works fine on Gmail for Android as well as in the Gmail webmail.

Comment: hey @lukeA it does the same thing as mentioned above in the question, have you tested?

Comment: It opens the dialing app when clicking in Gmail for Android.

Comment: Hey @lukeA i tried it on android 4.4.4 and gmail app version 4.9 it does not work as expected.

Comment: Worked fine on Android 4.4.2 with Gmail 4.9. What does you hyperlink look like?

Comment: <a target="_blank" href="tel:+91-999-999-9999">Make call</a> @lukeA

Comment: Not reproducible - `<a target="_blank" href="tel:+91-999-999-9999">link</a>` works fine here.

Comment: hey @lukeA it will be really helpful if u can send me that demo to my mail id desai.abhay22@gmail.com thanks in advance